# Wicket SortableDataProvider sorting with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, sorting, wicket

I am using wicket 6.19.0 and Hibernate 4

I am using a sortable data provider, i have the iterator and paging methods sorted.

Sorting is now on the agenda, does anyone have a good pattern in order to sort using the SortableDataProvider?

Answer (score 0):

Use SortableDataProvider's sortParam to set Hibernate's "sort by" asc/desc.